# Rest Api not working with Iframe in form data

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have created one api with post request.

```
register_rest_route('myapi/v1', '/post_flyer', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'api_post_flyer',
    ));
```

I have to submit form data with `<iframe></iframe>` or `<script></script>` tag in post content.

When i am try to check this api using postman, every time its display the error like "No route found",

```
"code": "rest_no_route",
"message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
"data": {
    "status": 404
}
```

While whole functionality is there, 
So i want to know that how to enable api to accept iframe and html tags for post content?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **"/"** from route and try using add action like

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {    
register_rest_route('myapi/v1', 'post_flyer', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'api_post_flyer',
        ));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
But normally its working, its display no route found error when i use <iframe> in post content